# pass loop parameters to closure inside closure

Tags: javascript, loops, closures, parameter-passing

I'm trying to give the for loop parameter i to the inner closure because I want to identify my decoded audio (that's put inside buffer).

This code gives an error: e is undefined. It works however when removing the )(test) by which I mean that test is equal to list.length for all the results however I want them to have the value of the current parameter i when called.

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) { //load in every url
    requestArray.push(new XMLHttpRequest());
    requestArray[i].open('GET', list[i].url, true);
    requestArray[i].responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    test = i;
    requestArray[i].onload = (function (e) {
        //Async method: ASK J
        context.decodeAudioData(e.target.response, (function (buffer) { //Async method
            console.log(test);
            if (!buffer) {
                alert('error decoding file data: ');
                return;
            }
        })(test),

        function (e) {
            console.log('Error decoding audio file', e)
        });
    })(test);

    requestArray[i].onerror = function () {
        alert('BufferLoader: XHR error');
    }

    requestArray[i].send();
}
```

Comment: where is "context" in the onload coming from. Im surprised that isn't throwing an error

Comment: context is defined at the beginning of the script: it's webaudio stuff but it is not related to this problem: var context = new webkitAudioContext();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
    requestArray.push(new XMLHttpRequest());
    requestArray[i].open('GET', list[i].url, true);
    requestArray[i].responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    requestArray[i].onload = (function (i) {
        return function (resp) {
            // i: index in requestArray
            // resp: the response object passed when the onload event occurs

            context.decodeAudioData(
                resp.target.response,
                (function(test) {
                    return function (buffer) {
                        console.log(test);
                        if (!buffer) {
                            alert('error decoding file data: ');
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }(i)),
                function(e) { console.log('Error decoding audio file', e)}
            );
        }
    }(i));
    requestArray[i].onerror = function() {
        alert('BufferLoader: XHR error');
    }
    requestArray[i].send();
}
```

**Please note that for a closure to be created a function must return a function.**

This is a closure:

```
(function(){
    var a = "b";
    return function(){ alert(b); }
}());
```

This is evaluated AS SOON as it is seen:

```
(function(){
    var a = "b";
}());
```

Comment: but where does decodeAudioData fit in this? decodeAudioData is also a calback function; where is my inner closure?

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not do what you want it to. Instead of binding `test` as an argument, you immediately call your anonymous functions with the argument `test` and pass their returned results as arguments to `decodeAudioData`. I'd suggest fixing this first. E.g. by using [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Comment: could you elaborate please? I'm not really familiar with prototyping

Comment: It's not about prototyping. You just need to write `myFunc.bind(window, test)`, and this will turn `myFunc` into a Function object that, when called, will pass `test` as the first argument to `myFunc` and `window` as `this` (the receiver object).

Comment: `.bind` is a tricky function for certain applications because not only does it bind parameters to the function, but also binds the caller instance.

Comment: Right. [goog.partial](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/closure_goog_base.js.source.html#line1106) from the Google Closure library fixes this :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess I would try a syntax like this (I would also take a more modular approach, with several declared function)

```
for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++){ //load in every url
        requestArray.push(new XMLHttpRequest());
        requestArray[i].open('GET', list[i].url, true);
        requestArray[i].responseType = 'arraybuffer';
        test = i;
        requestArray[i].onload = (function(outerIndex){
                        return function (e) { //Async method: ASK J
                context.decodeAudioData(e.target.response, 
                    (function(index){
                        return function(buffer) {  //Async method
                            console.log(index);
                            if (!buffer) {
                                alert('error decoding file data: ');
                                return;
                            }
                        };  
                    })(outerIndex),  function(e) { console.log('Error decoding audio file', e)});
        };})(test);


        requestArray[i].onerror = function() {
            alert('BufferLoader: XHR error');
        }

        requestArray[i].send();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you put

```
})(test);
```

You run the function at that time (not when the event occurs) passed test like e.
I don't understand "e is undefined" e is i.

Could you try to put "var" where you define the variable test and remove ")(test)"? I think the issue is in scope of test.